# Haskell does not support the C++ overloading style in which functions with different types share a common name

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell. When I gone through following documentation.
https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html

It is mentioned that "Haskell does not support the C++ overloading style in which functions with different types share a common name." I am not getting this statement, I guess ad-hoc polymorphism (which is done by using type classes) is equivalent to method overloading in C++, Java. Can some body explain me is my understanding correct ?

```
class Equal a where

    isEquals :: a -> a -> Bool


type Id = Int
type Name = String

data Employee = Engineer Id Name 

data Student = Student Id Name

getEmpId (Engineer empId _) = empId
getStudId (Student studId _) = studId

instance Equal Employee where
    isEquals emp1 emp2 = getEmpId emp1 == getEmpId emp2

instance Equal Student where
    isEquals stud1 stud2 = getStudId stud1 == getStudId stud2
```

In the above snippet 'isEquals' function is applied to two different types Employee, Student which is equivalant of overloading in C++, Java. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: There is only one `isEquals` function - its type is `Equal a => a -> a -> Bool`. Typeclasses give you much more power than method overloading, so to say they are "equivalent" is wrong. Already your `Equals` class precludes `isEquals :: Int -> Char -> Bool` which is something you cannot get from simple method overloading. Haskell typeclasses are more similar to OO interfaces - where you define a specification in advance which can be implemented by multiple types (although there are again plenty of differences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partially, yes. However, keep in mind that signature of your `isEquals` is always `a -> a`. In C++ you could easily write:

```
int foo(int a, int b)
int foo(int a, char b)
int foo(char a, char b)
```

By using typeclasses you're only able to get first and third function, never the second.

UPDATE 1:

as noted in comments, you can achieve the second version by using `MultiParamTypeClasses` extension (if you're using GHC). Still, there is fourth version:

```
int foo(int a, int a, int a)
```

which has wrong arity if you use a typeclass, but is perfectly fine in C++.

Comment: I guess we can achieve 'int foo(int a, char b)' using by enabling Haskell extension 'MultiParamTypeClasses'.

Comment: @HariKrishna exactly, [and here's an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a289e9b9bdc1acf). Or actually, a [much simpler one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2d7c7b2c571a107)

Comment: certainly, but first, it's an extension, second - you still have a sigle decision point of how many types are there and third - there is always a constant amount of arguments, which is not guaranteed by C++

Comment: The typeclass also prevents you (I think) from overloading on arity. A multi parameter type class would allow you to define `int foo(int a, char b)`, but I don't think it helps you define `int foo(int a, int b, int c)`.

Comment: @chepner Well, one could be enable a bunch of extensions and use `class C a where foo :: a` and `instance C (Int -> Char -> Int) where ...`. This can "work" if `foo` is used in the right contexts, but it can require some annotations in others. For variadic functions there's also the `printf` hack. All of this is not very idiomatic, and should be avoided if possible, IMHO.

Comment: @chi Thanks. I'm not that familiar with `MultiParamTypeClasses` (or most extensions, really), so I wasn't sure where this fell on the spectrum of possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Type classes in Haskell are just a fancy way of providing implicit arguments. Consider this code:

```
data Equal a = Equal {isEquals :: a -> a -> Bool}


type Id = Int
type Name = String

data Employee = Engineer Id Name 

data Student = Student Id Name

getEmpId (Engineer empId _) = empId
getStudId (Student studId _) = studId

equalEmployee :: Equal Employee
equalEmployee = Equal {
    isEquals = \emp1 emp2 -> getEmpId emp1 == getEmpId emp2
}

equalStudent :: Equal Student
equalStudent = Equal {
    isEquals stud1 stud2 = getStudId stud1 == getStudId stud2
}

equalThree :: Equal a -> a -> a -> a -> Bool
equalThree e a1 a2 a3 = isEquals e a1 a2 && isEquals e a2 a3
```

What is the difference with your code? Well, if in your code we define

```
equalThree :: Equal a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
equalThree a1 a2 a3 = isEquals a1 a2 && isEquals a2 a3
```

The difference is that in your code (with classes) compiler finds a suitable class instance by itself, using given types. In my variant, required instances are provided explicitly. But that's the only difference; in fact, your variant would be converted to mine under the hood.

So, classes do not override anything. They are just a fancy syntax for data types and implicit arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  The only way to get the equivalent of C++ (function; Haskell has no methods!) overloading would be a type class

```
class SomeFunc a where
    someFunc :: a
```

Now you can define `someFunc` at (more or less) any type you want.  But you would have to declare it for every function you want to 'overload', whereas in C++ it's implicit simply from having two functions with the same name.

Haskell's type system is designed to provide something C++'s doesn't: standardized behavior (expressed as laws).  So, for example, the standard Prelude defines

```
class Eq a where
    (==), (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

and now you *know* every `==` operator in the language takes two arguments, of the same type, and returns a boolean; by contrast, C++ is perfectly fine with something like

```
mystring operator (==)(mystring x, string y) {
    return x + " == " + y;
}
```

that breaks all of those 'reasonable' rules.  Beyond that, type classes come with laws, e.g.

```
x == x = True -- x total
x == y = y == x
x == y = True => y == z = True => x == z = True
```

which are additional restrictions on *all* instances.  That's made a lot easier by the fact that every instance is an instance of *this* type class (defined in one place), which gives you a single place to define what those laws are.  In C++, such 'laws' have more of the character of conventions.  Furthermore, C++ is explicitly designed to allow things like  using + for string concatenation, while Haskell is explicitly designed to dis-allow things like that (that's what 'Haskell does not supporth the C++ overloading style' probably means), so laws have to have more of the character of conventions in C++, which individual types can ignore if it's convenient for them.